python requirements.txt - requirement specifier for Linux docker on real Apple hardware?
I am trying to create a requirements.txt to behave on

Linux
MacOS
Linux container running on MacOS (M1 laptop) in Docker. I THINK this needs to behave like in (2)

My scenario is similar to requirements.txt for pytorch for both CPU and GPU platforms except that question didn't have docker.
I have this in my requirements.txt ...
torch==2.2.1+cpu ; sys_platform == "linux"
torch==2.2.1 ; sys_platform != "linux"

and I run  pip install -r requirements.txt --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
It works as expected on Linux (and also for a docker build on Linux base) and works as expected on MacOS because sys.platform there is 'darwin'. The 2.2.1+cpu version only is available for Linux.
However building in docker on MacOS, on a M1 laptop, I see ...
docker build -t my-image:latest -f Dockerfile .
// SNIP
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==2.2.1+cpu (from versions: 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==2.2.1+cpu

Can I have one requirements.txt that will work in all cases? I can't find requirement specifier to know what the underlying physical hardware is (assuming that is the actually the real issue?)

cpu is cpu not platform. Is there sys_cpu ?

What is your base image in FROM statement in Dockerfile?

I also have the exact same issue on Ubuntu (works) vs Docker on M1 Laptop (torch 2.3.1+cpu -- No matching distribution found. Did you find a workaround or resolution? I expected Docker to behave the same, and for -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html to work in my requirements.txt for both!

I wonder if the right version cannot be found due to the "%2Bcpu" character in the name of wheels @ https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
